# How to find first div id on click on anchor tag using j-query

Tags: jquery

I have done some work on click on anchor tag. I have multiple nested div. So If I click on anchor tag then it will return first / big div id. 
I want to work in below click event of anchor -

```
$('.show-details a').click(function(){

});
```

And The HTML code is -

```
<div id="main-div1" class="main-div-class">
    <div id="sub-div" class="sub-div-class">
        <div class="show-detail">
            <a href="#"> show </a>
        <div>

   </div>
</div>
<div id="main-div2" class="main-div-class">
    <div id="sub-div" class="sub-div-class">
        <div class="show-detail">
            <a href="#"> show </a>
        <div>

   </div>
</div>
```

How can I find particular div id(main-div1 or main-div2) from click on particular anchor tag
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .closest() also, the selector `.show-details a` is wrong, it should be `.show-detail a`

```
$('.show-detail a').click(function(){
    var $main = $(this).closest('.main-div-class');
    alert($main.attr('id'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RX2MK/)

Comment: Thanks Arun, Its giving best result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show-details a').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('div.main-div-class').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't give ID as asked in question

Comment: Thanks Raidri, Its giving best result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GVtpB/)**

```
$('.show-detail a').click(function () {
    var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div.main-div-class');
    alert(parentDiv.attr('id'));
});
```